# Are quantum states unit vectors in the space defined by their basis vectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Also, if this is true, does this mean that the possible values of some quantum state are geometrically represented by unit spheres of $n$-dimensions and does thinking of these quantum states in this geometric way give us special ability to think about questions that other methods don't afford us?

Comment: It's a bad way to think about it.  How do you represent the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vert 1\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\vert 2\rangle$ as a circle, given one coefficient is purely imaginary?

Comment: Well couldn't it be a unit circle that happens to be in a complex space instead of real space?

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to the comment by ZeroTheHero, when referring to quantum states, to be more accurate we talk about *rays* in the Hilbert space, and not usually vectors (or unit vectors as you stated). Remember that a ray in Hilbert space is the *collection* of vectors that differ only by a phase factor.

We can however talk about "unit rays" as oppose to unit vectors, in which case a unit ray in a Hilbert space is the set  $$\{\lambda \psi : \lambda \in \mathbb C : \lambda\ne 0 \ \text{and}\ \ |\lambda|=1\}$$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary complex number (with unit magnitude).

An important point to note is that the magnitude, or length of a state in a Hilbert space is not physically distinct from a state that is longer or shorter (their relative "directions" are relevant, or value of their inner products).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the titular question is certaintly yes (I assume you're thinking about pure states). As to the follow-up, a complex $n$-dimensional unit vector indeed corresponds to the surface of a $2n$-dimensional sphere, but as per @ZeroTheHero I think this seldom helps us think about questions. One case in which it does help is in considering random unitaries acting on the state, which correspond to taking a random unit vector on the surface of such as sphere, so then we get to use the mathematical machinery of [random matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix) and SU$(n)$.